# error: cast from int (*)(const char*, stat*) to unsigned int loses precision

Tags: c++

i am trying to compile the below code in both 32-bit and 64-bit modes.
But the thing here is, no issues with 32-bit, there is compilation error in 64 Bit.

please give me your suggestion for the successful compilation in 64-bit mode.

```
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "sys/stat.h"

int main(void)
{
  int val;

  val = int((unsigned(stat)>>8))&0xff;
  printf("val =  %d\n",  val);

  return 0;
}

 [avinta@la-lnx61dev01 ~]$ g++ -m64 bit_ops.cpp
 bit_ops.cpp: In function âint main()â:
 bit_ops.cpp:9: error: cast from âint (*)(const char*, stat*)throw ()â to     âunsigned intâ loses precision
 [avinta@la-lnx61dev01 ~]$
```

Comment: maybe read the [documentation for stat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html). And/or describe what you are trying to do, because the code you posted has an error which the compiler successfully diagnosed

Answer (score 3):

You successfully included `sys/stat.h` which gives you access to the function: `int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);` whose address you are trying to cast to an unsigned. On a 32 bit platform this is ok (since possibly both the address and `unsigned` are 32 bit values), but for your 64 bit the `unsigned^ (possibly) is 32 bit and the address is 64 bit. That's why the compiler is complaining about losing precision.

See more about stat: http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

But why actually do you want to cast the address of a function in bitwise operations?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your suggestion/answer. Actually we are porting one existing project from 32-bit to 64-bit. the above typical code line already is in the project

Comment: umm.... it's still not clear to me why do you want to cast the address of a function?

Comment: don't know. it is already existing code